# Is there any way to manage child window location from parent window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.location

I have one form

```
<form target="_blank">
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

after submitting this `<form>` whatever action response is open in new tab. i want to manage this tab location url from my form submission page.

if `<form>` page is close so that i can change window.location of target tab

is this possible???

Comment: what do you mean by manage location ?

Comment: what do you mean by `manage`?

Comment: i want to trigger/manage window.location.href of target tab from parent page

Comment: Are you saying you want to specify the url the new tab opens in? That's what your server program will do.

Comment: @JeevanJose yes i want to specify the url on new tab when main tab is closed by user(in window.unload event)

Comment: What language are you using on your server?

Answer (score 0):

You better do some tricky Javascript code.

```
var openWindows = new Array;

window._open = window.open;

window.open = function (URL, name, specs, replace) {
    var newWindow = window._open(URL, name, specs, replace);

    // store newWindow in an array to refer later
    openWindows.push(newWindow);
}
```

So you can store a list of windows opened from your page.

Note that you can only access other windows via scripts from same domain.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer but i am not using window.open() m submitting <form> n giving the target=_blank.

Comment: Hmm, I was focus to your question title and thought using <form> is just an example that you use to describe the problem. Anyway, could you consider a work-around: using ajaxForm to submit the form and using overrided window.open() to open destination URL in success callback?

Comment: can you give example if possible